# Can't access DataTables instance

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable that I initialize on page load. Everything works as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dtTable = $('#table_pins').DataTable({
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [
          { className: "dt-nowrap", "targets": [4] },
          { "targets": [1, 2], "visible": false, "searchable": false }
        ],
        "bFilter": true,
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
        },
        responsive: true
    });

    dtTable.on('search.dt', function(){
      reloadMarkers();
    });

});
```

On a search event I need to iterate through the rows again and update map pins so I need to access the DataTables instance. I tried:

```
function reloadMarkers() {
    $('#table_pins').DataTable().rows().iterator('row', function(context, index){
        var data = $(this.row(index).data());
    });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=table_pins - Cannot reinitialise 
DataTable. For more information about this error, please see 
http://datatables.net/tn/3
```

I looked at the docs and added `"retrieve": true` on initialization but I still get the error. Why isn't it retrieving the instance since its already initialized?

Comment: Try to use ```dtTable``` variable instead of reinitializing ```$('#table_pins').DataTable()``` again

Comment: It says dtTable undefined. I also tried creating a global variable but still got undefined.

Comment: Try remove ```var``` in front of dtTable

Comment: Tried that. Still undefined.

Comment: Please share you full code then. Your search event is unclear.

Comment: Added function as requested.

Comment: I think you can just iterate the table right away without having to access datatables

Comment: Not in this case because I need to access hidden columns.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and I'll gladly take a serious look into it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial error

> DataTables warning: table id=table_pins - Cannot reinitialise 
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see 
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

Is caused by your attempt to call DataTable constructor at the same DOM element (as being said in the comments), instead of accessing already existing DataTable instance

> ```
>     $('#table_pins').DataTable().rows().iterator('row', function(context, index){
> ```

Your `undefined` errors, most probably, is the scope issue - maybe your `reloadMarkers()` definition resides outside of `$(document).ready()` callback (can't tell for sure without wider code sample.

It's not that clear what you're trying to achieve with `reloadMarkers()`.

What I would recommend is change your `reloadMarkers()` to something, like:

```
function reloadMarkers() {
    dtTable.rows({search:'applied'}).every(function(){
        //do what you wanted to do with your row data, index, 
        //using this.data(), this.index() methods
    });
}
```

bearing in mind that it should be placed inside `$(document).ready()`.

Or, event better, if you don't call that function on other occasions than table search, you can make your code simplier and put function body inside `search` event callback.